# ¿Como eliminar un numero repetido en un arreglo? C++

Tags: c++

Saludos, estoy estudiando programación en c++ y se me a complicado en una parte del problema
El problema es siguiente:

> Realizar una clase que contenga un arreglo unidimensional de 30
>   números enteros (posiblemente repetidos) y obtenga como salida ese
>   mismo arreglo pero sin números repetidos. Un método ha de gragar datos
>   en el arreglo, otro método ha de excluir los repetidos y un tercer
>   método ha de mostrar el arreglo sin números repetidos. Incluir un
>   método constructor para inicializar el arreglo con un valor de ceros.

Ya hecho la parte de hacer una clase que contenga grabar datos y creo yo imprimir los datos, lo que me falla es como elimino los numeros repetidos, que por ejemplo el usuario pueda dar, ejemplo
el usario define un rango hasta el 5, y los valores que ingreso son 1, 2, 2, 4,67, ahora no me queda claro como imprimir los resultados pero sin que se repita los datos en teoría quedaría el resultado así 1,2,4,67.

De antemano desde ya agradezco su tiempo y la ayuda.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#define MAX 30
using namespace std;
//se esta definiendo la clase
class Grabar {
private:
    int n,i, array[30];
    int valor;
    void datos();
public:
    void tirar();
    void imprimir();
    void eliminar();
};

void Grabar::datos()
{
    cout << "**************************************************";
    cout << "\n";
    do{
        cout<<"\n\nCantidad de elementos a ingresar: ";
        cin>>n;
            if(n<=0)
                cout<<"...No seas payaso(a), ingresa una cantidad correcta: "<<endl;
            if(n>MAX)
                cout<<"...La cantidad maxima permitida es "<<MAX<<" : "<<endl;
    }
    while(n<=0 || n>MAX);
    cout << "**************************************************";
    cout << "\n";
}

void Grabar::tirar()
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"\n Elemento ["<<i<<"] ";
        cin>> array [i];
    }
    cout << "**************************************************";
    cout << "\n";
    cout<<"\n Elementos en el array: ";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"\n Elemneto ["<<i<<"]: "<<array[i];

    }


void Grabar::eliminar(){
    //Aca seria el codigo
}

void Grabar::imprimir()
{
    datos();
    cout << valor;
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Grabar d;
    d.imprimir();
    d.tirar();
    d.eliminar();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Quizás te ayude esta entrada:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836956/how-to-delete-duplicate-values-in-an-array Saludos,

Comment: @Ricky no creo que una entrada en inglés suponga una respuesta a alguien que busca respuestas en un sitio en español; tampoco creo que una respuesta de C# ayude a alguien que busca respuestas en C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto que te muestro a continuacion. El algoritmo para hacerlo está un poco rustico, pero funciona y puedes mejorarlo para que sea mas eficiente.

```
#include<iostream>
#define MAX 30

using namespace std;

class Grabar {

public:
    int len, arr[30];

    void leer();
    void eliminar_dup();
    void mostrar();

};

void Grabar::leer() {
    len = 0;
    int n;

    do {

        cout << "Introduzca la cantidad de valores (entre 1 y 30)" << endl;

        cin >> n;

        if(n < 1 || n > MAX)
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        else
            len = n;
    } while(n < 1 || n > MAX);

    cout << "Escriba los valores" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
}

void Grabar::eliminar_dup() {

    for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; j<len; j++) {
            ///Si encontramos un duplicado
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {

                ///Lo vamos intercambiando hasta que quede al final
                for(int k=j;k<len-1;k++)
                   swap(arr[k], arr[k+1]);

                ///Disminuimos la longitud en 1, lo que significa
                ///que se elimina un elemento
                len--;

                ///Disminuimos a j para que se quede en el mismo
                ///lugar (vease que el elemento que estaba en esa
                ///posicion fue eliminado, si no disminuimos j en 1
                ///nos saltamos un valor por analizar).
                j--;
            }
      }
}

void Grabar::mostrar() {

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " \n"[i==len-1];
}

int main() {

    Grabar x;

    x.leer();
    x.eliminar_dup();
    x.mostrar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Issac, muchas gracias por el ejemplo y si tienes razón entre mas simple creo que es mucho mejor, creo que es la respuesta que estaba buscando. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Tienes varias formas de eliminar números repetidos:

**Contenedor std::set**

`std::set` es un contenedor de la STL que almacena una lista de elementos ordenados y sin duplicados. Su uso es bastante simple:

```
std::set<int> numeros;
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
  int n;
  std::cout << "Introduce un número: ";
  std::cin >> n;
  numeros.insert(n);
}

std::cout << "Lista de números sin repeticiones:\n";
for( int numero : numeros )
  std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

**std::vector + std::sort + std::unique**

`std::vector` es el contenedor por excelencia de la STL. Almacena una lista de elementos sin ordenar, admite duplicados y, su gran ventaja, todos los elementos están en posiciones contiguas de memoria, por lo que su acceso es muy rápido al aprovechar las bondades de la caché.

`std::sort` es una utilidad de la STL que permite ordenar un rango de valores.

`std::unique` es una utilidad de la STL que dado un rango de elementos (iteradores de inicio y de final de rango), elimina todas las apariciones contiguas de elementos repetidos. Bueno, realmente no los elimina... los mueve al final del rango. Finalmente te devuelve un iterador al primer elemento duplicado.

```
std::vector<int> numeros;
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
  int n;
  std::cout << "Introduce un número: ";
  std::cin >> n;
  numeros.push_back(n);
}

// Primero ordenamos la secuencia
std::sort(numeros.begin(),numeros.end());

// Despues eliminamos los duplicados
numeros.erase(std::unique(numeros.begin(),numeros.end()),numeros.end());

std::cout << "Lista de números sin repeticiones:\n";
for( int numero : numeros )
  std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

Aunque pueda parecer un método más engorroso, este mecanismo es bastante más rápido que el anterior ante secuencias bastante largas... cuanto más largas mayor diferencia de velocidad.

**Contenedor std::set + std::tie**

Los dos métodos anteriores presentan un inconveniente y es que ordenan la secuencia inicial. Este método está pensado para mantener la secuencia original inalterada pero sin duplicados.

Si revisas la ayuda de `std::set` podrás observar que el método `insert()` devuelve un `std::pair`, que no es más que un objeto que permite almacenar una pareja de valores. El primer valor es un iterador al elemento insertado y el segundo valor es un booleano que indica si el elemento insertado es nuevo en el contenedor o si ya existía.

`std::tie` es una función que permite *explotar* ese objeto `std::pair` para recuperar sus elementos individuales. La gran ventaja de este método es que permite descartar valores que no nos interesan. Para tu caso particular únicamente te interesa el segundo valor, el booleano: si el mismo es true quiere decir que el elemento no existía en el contenedor.

La idea es combinar `std::set` y `std::tie` para identificar los elementos duplicados y eliminarlos sin necesidad de reorganizar el contenedor original:

```
std::vector<int> entrada{ 1,2,1,6,4,2,2,2,3 };
std::vector<int> salida;
std::set<int> detector;
for( numero : entrada)
{
  bool nuevo;
  std::tie(std::ignore,nuevo) = detector.insert(numero);
  if( nuevo )
    salida.push_back(numero); // solo se añaden los numeros no duplicados
}

for( int numero : salida)
  std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

`std::ignore` no es más que una especie de papelera, se usa para descartar valores que no necesitamos.

**Programando todo de cero**

Si tienes una secuencia y quieres eliminar los duplicados puedes optar por recorrer la secuencia de principio a fin y en cada iteración comparar el elemento actual con todos los anteriores... si hay coincidencia el elemento está duplicado y debes eliminarlo:

```
std::vector<int> entrada{ 1,2,1,6,4,2,2,2,3 };
std::vector<int> salida;

for( auto it = entrada.begin(); it != entrada.end(); ++it )
{
  bool duplicado = false;
  for( auto it2 = entrada.begin(); it2 != it; ++it2 )
  {
    if( *it == *it2 )
    {
      duplicado = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( !duplicado )
    salida.push_back(*it);
}

for( int numero : salida)
  std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

**Simplificando el ejemplo anterior**

También podemos darle un pequeño repaso al ejemplo anterior para aprovechar un poco la STL:

```
std::vector<int> entrada{ 1,2,1,6,4,2,2,2,3 };
std::vector<int> salida;

for( auto it = entrada.begin(); it != entrada.end(); ++it )
{
  if( std::count(entrada.begin(),it,*it) == 0 )
    salida.push_back(*it);
}

for( int numero : salida)
  std::cout << numero << '\n';
```

`std::count` te indica el número de veces que un valor determinado se repite en un rango. En este caso iteramos desde el inicio de la lista hasta el número inmediatamente anterior al que estamos comprobando y el número a buscar es el número actual:

```
//            (1)          (2)  (3)
std::count(entrada.begin(), it, *it)

// (1): inicio del rango = inicio de la lista
// (2): fin del rango = posición actual (no se incluye en la búsqueda)
// (3): valor a buscar = número actual
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @eferion , lo ley todo y  ya comprendí un poco mas a mi problema, gracias y saludos desde México

Comment: Chale, por mucho de las mejores respuestas que he leído en el sitio. Un aplauso amigo

Answer (score -1):

existen estructuras que te pueden ayudar, por ejemplo SET, el cual se refiere a que tu coleccion no almacenara elementos repetidos

lee:
http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=610:interfaces-set-y-sortedset-del-api-java-clases-hashset-y-treeset-ordenado-ejemplo-diferencias-cu00921c&catid=58:curso-lenguaje-programacion-java-nivel-avanzado-i&Itemid=180

ahora en c++ seria asi:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
std::set<int> s{1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: Creo que me revolvió un poco esto, pero con la ayuda de los demás e entendido un poco para resolver mi problema, gracias

Comment: @SoterRamirez si te ayudo mi respuesta al menos puntea +1

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con unique. Está definido en la biblioteca Algorithm. Quita todos los elementos consecutivos duplicados en un rango (first, last). La extracción la hace desplazando el rango de modo que los elementos borrados se sobrescriben. Sólo el primer elemento de cada grupo de elementos iguales se deja. Los elementos entre el viejo y el nuevo final o el rango se dejan intactos. Devuelve un iterador al primer elemento duplicado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>



 int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1};

   std::vector<int>::iterator last;  
    last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    // 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 // 
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); 
     it != last; ++it) { std::cout << *it << " ";
      } 
      std::cout << "\n"; 
      return 0;
      }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `unique`? ¿Cual es el formato de la llamada? ¿Qué retorna? ¿Qué consideraciones hay que tener en cuenta para usarlo?

Comment: Mejor editas la respuesta para agregar esa explicación. Asi será de más provecho para todos.

Comment: Lo que se buscaba en la pregunta era eliminar **todos** los duplicados, estuviesen o no en posiciones consecutivas.

Comment: Basta para mí, no voy a ser parte de esto. Parece que se tratara de quitar puntos sea por preguntar, sea por responder. Fué un gusto

Comment: Si elaboras una buena respuesta obtendrás puntuaciones positivas ... si te equivocas, negativas. Arregla lo que no funciona y esas puntuaciones negativas es convertirán en positivas. En cualquier caso, la puntuación, más allá de desbloquear ciertas funciones, no sirve para mucho, yo no me agobiaría por la puntuación y me preocuparía, eso sí, en elaborar buenas respuestas.

Comment: Yo me he llevado puntuaciones negativas ocasionalmente, a veces merecidas por responder algo que no tenía nada que ver (es lo que tiene leer rápido) y en otras ocasiones por motivos que desconozco totalmente... pero aquí sigo, si elaboras buenas respuestas los negativos serán algo exótico

Comment: Racionalizar naturalizando un bullying elitista, socialmente aceptado, me parece un horror del que no voy a participar, aún en nombre del avance. Están equivocados y ni siquiera lo ven. Allá Uds